# FFI libs dependancies on cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, ffi

I've created a library that wraps a C library. The C library is very lightweight, so the .lib file is directly in the project directory.

I've instructed Cargo on where to find the library in the build.rs file

```rust
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=lib");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=myclib");
```

and everything compiles correctly.

However, if I try to use the library from another Rust project, I get a linker error stating that it can't find the .lib file that my Rust wrapper depends on.

How are these cases usually managed to incorporate dependencies?

Comment: Usually you compile the code with [`cc`](https://docs.rs/cc) and not ship a prebuilt binary (although that's also possible).

Comment: the C library is not mine and not open. I have only lib, dll and headers